# sending image captured from flash webcam to java based server from flash stage

Tags: java, flash, jsp

I have jsp application which let end user to capture image from webcam for which I used flash to get access to user webcam to trigger it.
Till now it's fine and also got success to capture image from webcam but it remain on flash stage, so I searched throughly for this then I came across one website "xarg.org" where i got webcam plugin which let to catch webcam image to html canvas(which only work in IE 9 and mozila FF and other browser those support HTML 5) and post it web-server but for that they using PHP which I don't speak, I want it to be done using JSP.
I need to read bitmap data from flash stage which is captured and want to convert it to image/ byte array so to pass it to JSP ?
Is there any jsp script like PHP which will post image to server and also store in database?
What i want to do is make sense or it won't possible?

```
<object id="whatever" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="282" height="180"codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,115,0">
<param name="src" value="./swf/jscam.swf"/>
<param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF"/>
<param name="quality" value="best"/>
<embed name="whatever" src="./swf/jscam.swf" width="282" height="180" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" quality="best" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/index.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash">
</embed>
</object>
```

here is code which i used to get access to user webcam, now i want to catch bitmap of webcam and post/save same to any directory of localhost but using JSP not PHP. There are numerous examples using PHP.

Comment: You need to show some code and have a specific problem, not 100 vague questions.

Comment: @beeerbajay:I added code for accessing webcam now fine can you help me from that? can we capture image from flash to HTML IMG tag so as to get it's form reference.

Comment: What is this `jscam`? From where did you get it? Is there documentation?

Comment: @beerbajay:jscam is a flash file which I made in flash cs6 to access webcam. in which I added two buttons to capture image and save image.but problem is onclicking save button it pop ups save dialogue box to select location for saving file which I don't want.it should take place implicitly in background which is not happening.