# exporting Image from flash to JSP page

Tags: java, flash, jsp

```
<object id="whatever" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="282" height="180"codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,115,0">
    <param name="src" value="./swf/jscam.swf"/>
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF"/>
    <param name="quality" value="best"/>
    <embed name="whatever" src="./swf/jscam.swf" width="282" height="180" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" quality="best" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/index.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash">
    </embed>
</object>
```

I have this code for embedding flash in jsp to acces webcam but my query is how do I pass image captured on flash stage to JSP page so as to add in MySQL database and same to post it on localhost directory

Comment: possible duplicate of [sending image captured from flash webcam to java based server from flash stage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10780555/sending-image-captured-from-flash-webcam-to-java-based-server-from-flash-stage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Capture an image from the video object that you connected to the webcam by using BitmapData's draw() method.
Then use a JPEG encoder (comes with flex or google one) to convert the BitmapData to ByteArray.

You can now send the byte array as post data to the page of your choosing with the URLLoader class.

Comment: If you are asking how you can do it from the HTML page without editing the swf: you can't. You're going to have to make the swf send the screenshot.

Comment: I captured image in flash using draw() method but question is that remains on flash stage i want save it on server automatically once captured button pressed adn one more using JAVA or JSP only